# input the letter f or any letter and cout an alphabet pattern like a abc abcd abcde abcdef but it only works if i press 0

Tags: c++, char, cmath

So far nothing happens when you enter f it only works when 0 is entered but I want it so when you press f you get this a ab abc abcd abcde abcdef

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int f = 0;
int z;
cout << "";
while(cin >> f)
{
    if(f == 0)
    {
        cout << "ABCDEF\nABCDE\nABCD\nABC\nAB\nA";
        break;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: New to programming or not, surely you could do something about that title, dude. Some punctuation within the question wouldn't harm either...

Comment: It is not possible to read keystrokes in standard C++.  Standard streams like `cin` don't do that.

Comment: so your saying i can only use numbers?

Comment: You might be interested in our [list of good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to make your program do what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char c = 0;  // we want chars, not integers.
  int z;
  cout << "";
  while (cin >> c)
  {
    if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') // test for the range we want
    {
      // print all glyphs from a to 'c'
      for (char i = 'a'; i <= c; ++i)
        cout << i;
      cout << '\n';
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help but we get this error                                 
     main.cpp:10:21: error: expected primary-expression before '<' token
     if ('a' <= c && < c <= 'z') // test for the range we want

Comment: @matt: The answerer had a typo, which I've fixed.

Comment: It's a pity you didn't go for a portable solution but this is clear.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `f` is an int.  When you press the key 'f', the `cin` istream tries to set the `int` to 'f', which isn't a number, so the conversion from a character to a number fails.

That failure sets the bad-bit in `cin`, which breaks out of the while loop.

Comment: ok thanks for the help but im not sure how to get the conversion working i just want to enter f and have that pattern be on the screen, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Reading the input into a `char` is the easy bit: `std::cin >> c` for a `char c` will do it.

The fun bit is writing a *portable* way of printing the letters up to a certain character. Here's one way:

```
// Prints up to and including 'c'.
// Outputs the alphabet if 'c' is not a lower case letter.
void print(char c)
{
    static const char s[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for (std::size_t i = 0; s[i]; ++i){
        std::cout << s[i];
        if (s[i] == c){
            std::cout << '\n';
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This function loops until god knows when c is not in the range a-z

Comment: Hence my second comment; although we could clamp the output by putting s[i] as the loop conditional. You know I might just do that!

Comment: im pretty much just trying write a program that inputs a letter from A to Z and displays all the letters similar to the following output (which is based on the input of F):
ABCDEF
ABCDE
ABCD
ABC
AB
A

Answer (score 0):

If you enter f you cause an error because it is expecting an integer. You can convert the a char to an integer. If you want to turn a result if you enter f you have to options:

1.

```
char input;
std:cin >> input;
if((int)input == 102){
   .....
```

2.

```
char input;
std:cin >> input;
if(input == 'f'){
    .....
```

EDIT:
If you want to print the Alphabet in descending order Michael Roy had a nice solutions but in accesnding order

```
 if....
    for(char i = input; i >= 'a'; --i)
       cout << i - 32; //the 32 is for converting the lower case char into upper case
    cout << '\n';
```

So in total it could look something like this:

```
char input;
std:cin >> input;
if('a' < input < 'z'){
     for(char i = input; i >= 'a'; --i)
        cout << i - 32;
     cout << '\n';
 }else{
     cout << "Not a valid input";
 }
 System("Pause");//so the console doesn't close automatically
```

Comment: im pretty much just trying write a program that inputs a letter from A to Z and displays all the letters similar to the following output (which is based on the input of F):
ABCDEF
ABCDE
ABCD
ABC
AB
A

Comment: I edited my answer hopefully this will bring more carification